# Using MOSFET as a voltage controlled current source

Tags: mosfet, current-source, current-sink

I am trying to make an  electronic component that will do the following:

Vc is the control voltage, it can change the current thru the device.

I need Vx independent of the the current, that means current is fixed whatever the Vx is.

How should I do it?

I was thinking about a MOSFET but, the change in drain and source voltage could change the current.

[image]

Comment: You need to put in a feedback loop to compensate for everything you mentioned plus temperature effects etc.

Comment: @Antonio51 also called "voltage-controlled current source" like it says in the title.

Comment: Your diagram is for a high-side current source. A low-side current source is easier. If you describe your problem in more detail, we may be able to tell which is necessary. Here is a high-side current source. https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa867/slaa867.pdf Realize that it is only going to work over a range of input voltages.

Comment: Here are some questions you must answer before anyone can give you a definitive answer that would work for you: 1) What maximum current do you want for your load? 2) What range should we expect for Vx? 3) What is your desired Vc-to-I relationship? 4) Where and how is Vc produced? 4) Do you have a stable voltage source to power this circuit other than Vx? 5) What is the load?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of such a circuit.

Some specifications must obviously be done ...
as max current, max voltage, voltage control window levels, and some others ...

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to make a voltage controlled current source using op-amps, but here is a simple circuit using an NPN and PNP transistor. It's pretty linear once you get past the offset due to the the base-emitter voltage.

[image: Current Source NPN and PNP]

Diode D1 compensates for base-emitter voltage of Q2.

You can also use a PMOS device:

[image: Current Source NPN and PMOS]

And an NJFET provides a linear response almost down to zero input and output, as well as output within 1 volt of supply rail.

[image: Current Source NJFET and PNP]

Answer (score 1):

Use a resistor in the source and an opamp to  regulate the I*R drop across that R by driving the gate of the FET.

Comment: While this is correct, a diagram would help.